# How to create tabledestination on a different worksheet

Tags: vba

I want to create a pivot table by using pivottables.add. But how can I set a tabledestination if I want to create a pivot table on a different worksheet but the same workbook. I used tabledestination:=workbooks("sheet12"),range("A3"). But it has bugs in it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try, Declaring and assigning variables simplifies the code and looks good.

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Target As Range

Set Ws = Sheets("Sheet12")
Set Target = Ws.Range("a3")

   
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Sheet1!R1C1:R4C3", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:=Target, TableName:="pivotable1", DefaultVersion:= _
    xlPivotTableVersion14
```

Comment: it says compile error: expected experssion at tabledestination:=

Comment: @LucasZong, If there is already a pivot table on another sheet, an error may occur. I don't know the cause of the error, but try deleting the pivot table of the sheet.